# MS Access 2003 runtime?

Tags: ms-access, runtime

Can anyone confirm if there's an access 2003 runtime available to allow users to run apps without needing the full version of access on their pc?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Yes there is an A2003 runtime, only it was included within the A2003 Visual Studio (IIRC) which a. had to be purchased by the developer and then could be distributed (free) with the developed app so it did cost and secondly can no longer be purchased from Microsoft as they no longer support A2003 (though you may be able to get hold of it through other sources).

It may be possible for you to check the database using A2007 runtime which is available from the Microsoft Website. A2003 apps should run under A2007 / runtime but there are some restrictions so you do need to check it out first"

Comment: Actually the A2003 runtime was included in Visual Studio Tools for Office.   This is *NOT* the same product as Visual Studio.

Comment: The biggest issue with the A2007 runtime and legacy apps is the ribbon and custom toolbars/menu. If you don't have any of those, you're home free.